# Extjs window htmleditor big cursor in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs4.2

I'm using *Ext 4.2.1.883* in the below fiddle and there seems to be a big cursor blinking as soon as the window is closed.

This is happening only in IE (tested in Internet Explorer 11).

Just checking if anyone has an idea of how to overcome this.

Here is the link to fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hp8

This is how it looks the first time :
[image]

then you run the fiddle again and you see the below :

[image]

Comment: Work fine for me (Tested in IE9 and IE11) where exactly you hover it is "big"?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, well actually its appearing if you try multiple times, I tried 3 times and it appeared

Comment: You mean this occurs randomly? You using IE11?

Comment: Windows8 with Desktop-Mode or Metro-interface?

Comment: windows8 desktopmode

Comment: attached is the screenshot

Comment: Can you confirm that you have all Windows Update updates installed, and that Internet Explorer 11 is up to date? Please do so, and share the version number of IE. You can find this in the gear icon under "About Internet Explorer."

Comment: Your problem is with the cursor or that black band that appears in the background, did not understand the reason for the screenshot. Can explain, please :)

Comment: that's what is appearing when the window is closed, the next time you run the fiddle it will appear in the html editor

Comment: IE version : 11.0.9600.1663

Comment: @user3487063 It appears as though your IE is a little behind; would you please install all available updates in Windows Update at your earliest convenience. I'm curious if this issue repros in the latest version.

Comment: Only comment: Sound likes a bug in graphic driver

Comment: @JonathanSampson, I installed all available updates, and still its there. Appearing if you run the fiddle multiple times

Comment: I too am unable to repro this; may in fact be a hardware issue. Does it repro from any other machine(s) running the same version of IE 11?